# If function with different values for two buttons

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, button

I need two buttons with if functions

1) First condition is fulfilled:

> If enter number 2 — true, if number<2 and if number>2 —INCORRECTLY.

2) Second condition must be:

> If enter number 3 — true, if number<3 and if number>3 —INCORRECTLY.

The second condition is not fulfilled. How can I fulfill both conditions?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>ENTER A NUMBER:</p>
<input id="demo" type="text">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">VERIFY</button>
<p id="message"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var message, x;
    message = document.getElementById("message");
    message.innerHTML = "";
    x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
     try { 
        if(x == "2")  throw "TRUE !"  ;
  if(isNaN(x)) throw "not a number";
        x = Number(x);
  if(x > 2)    throw "INCORRECTLY";
  if(x < 2)   throw "INCORRECTLY";  }
        catch(err) { message.innerHTML = "ANSWER " + err ;    }}
</script>
</body>
</html>
<body>
<p>ENTER A NUMBER:</p>
<input id="demo" type="text">
<button type="buttonA" onclick="myFunctionA()">VERIFY</button>
<p id="message"></p>
<script>
function myFunctionA() {
    var message, x;
    message = document.getElementById("message");
    message.innerHTML = "";
    x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
     try { 
        if(x == "3")  throw "TRUE !"  ;
  if(isNaN(x)) throw "not a number";
        x = Number(x);
  if(x > 3)    throw "INCORRECTLY";
  if(x < 3)   throw "INCORRECTLY";  }
        catch(err) { message.innerHTML = "ANSWER " + err ;    }}

</script>
</body>
</table>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it herself.`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>ENTER A NUMBER:</p>

<input id="demo1" type="text">
<button type="buttonA" onclick="myFunction()">VERIFY</button>
<p id="message1"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var message, y;
    message = document.getElementById("message1");
    message.innerHTML = "";
    y = document.getElementById("demo1").value;
 
  try { 
        if( y == "2" )  throw "TRUE !"  ;
  if(isNaN(y)) throw "not a number";
        x = Number(y);
  if(y > 2 )    throw "INCORRECTLY";
  if(y < 2 )   throw "INCORRECTLY";  }
        catch(err) { message.innerHTML = "ANSWER " + err ;  
  }}
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
<body>
<p>ENTER A NUMBER:</p>

<input id="demo2" type="text">
<button type="buttonB" onclick="myFunctionB()">VERIFY</button>
<p id="message2"></p>

<script>
function myFunctionB() {
    var message, y;
    message = document.getElementById("message2");
    message.innerHTML = "";
    y = document.getElementById("demo2").value;
 
  try { 
        if( y == "3" )  throw "TRUE !"  ;
  if(isNaN(y)) throw "not a number";
        y = Number(y);
  if(y > 3 )    throw "INCORRECTLY";
  if(y < 3 )   throw "INCORRECTLY";  }
        catch(err) { message.innerHTML = "ANSWER " + err ;
   }}
  
</script>
</body>
</table>
</html>
```

`